# Instalação do git não está sendo reconhecida pelo Windows

Tags: git, zurb-foundation

Não sou familiarizado com o *bower* e instalação de pacotes, pois bem... 
Fui instalar o *Foundation Zurb*, para e-mail marketing instalou corretamente, mas quando dou o comando `foundation new` para criar um novo projeto, ele me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> ```
> You need Git installed to get started. Download it here: http://git-scm.com/downloads
> ```

Eu tenho o git instalado em minha maquina, por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você provavelmente não setou o *PATH* (caminho) de instalação corretamente para o Windows.
Você pode determinar o caminho da instalação dessa maneira:

- Clique com o botão direito do seu mouse em "Meu Computador" (*My Computer*)
- Selecione Propriedades (*Properties*)
- Selecione Avançado (*Advanced*)
- Clique em Variaveis de ambiente (*Environment Variables*)
- Selecione a variavel Caminho (*Path*)
- Clique em editar (*Edit*)
- Adicione o caminho ao seu Git na frente do campo valor de variavel (Variable value) e separe com um `;` do próximo registro (Obs. não adicione espaços entre ; e o próximo valor).

Comment: Não funcionou por favor da uma olhada se eu fizer certo 
https://i.imgur.com/ffV8e4D.png
https://i.imgur.com/aupCn6r.png
https://i.imgur.com/NXmdsNC.png

Comment: Não amigo, você deve colocar o path para git.exe ou seja, na pasta que colocou do Git você deve descer mais um nível e colocar Git/bin que é o caminho correto para o executável

Comment: valeuu colega , funcionou perfeitamente