# Erros ao criar projeto no Zurb Foundation

Tags: bower, zurb-foundation

Fiz a instalação do *Zurb Foundation* para Emails, mas ao fazer a instalação do projeto no diretório, ele esta me retornando vários erros *(estarei deixando a imagem do terminal já que são muitos)*, irei colocar apenas a primeira linha aqui no post.

> ```
> gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
> gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
> ```

**Imagens do terminal com o erro:**

[image: Erros no terminal]
<sup>Fonte: https://i.imgur.com/pTXUkX4.png</sup>
[image: Mais erros no terminal]
<sup>Fonte: https://i.imgur.com/oeY0bur.png</sup>

Comment: Instale o `Python2` e depois siga os procedimentos da resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283613/99718

Comment: Fiz a instalação do Python 2, funcionou, mas agora esta dando erros novos como na imagem: https://i.imgur.com/lH8fH2K.png
Obs (Tentei instalar o .NET framework SDK e especificar o caminho nas variáveis do sistema, mas mesmo assim o erro persistiu )

Comment: Você chegou a instalar *todos* os softwares que ele pede na imagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, instalei, tanto o .NET quanto o Visual C++